# django-import-export keyerror, when using OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

My models.py file is

```
from django.db import models

class companyDetail(models.Model):
    short_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "companyDetail"
        verbose_name_plural = "companyDetails"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class companyDescription(models.Model):
    comDetail = models.OneToOneField(
        companyDetail,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='coDetail',
        primary_key=True,
        )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    add_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "companyDescription"
        verbose_name_plural = "companyDescriptions"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comDetail.title
```

I am trying to break my model/table "company" into two diffrent modles "companyDetail" and "companyDescription" and connect them through OneToOneField.

It works fine when I am trying to add data via shell.

I am importing csv to django-import-export for model "companyDetail" it works fine but I am importing csv for model "companyDescription" it throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/abhirajput/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 453, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/abhirajput/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 267, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/abhirajput/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 261, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "/home/abhirajput/testpro/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/import_export/instance_loaders.py", line 31, in get_instance
field = self.resource.fields[key]
KeyError: 'comdetail'
```

Please help me in layman terms, as I am a civil engineer trying to get into web development and breaking tables(Breaking Bad).
If you have any other suggestion about breaking model/tables "company" into two models "companyDetail" and "companyDescription" please tell me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo:

```
KeyError: 'comdetail'

related_name='coDetail',
```

Comment: I have changed related_name='comDetail', but its still throwing same error

Comment: Have you made your migration after changing the typo?

Comment: yes i have made migrations. But the error still persist.

Comment: @E.Serra I have deliberately used related_name='coDetail' as it is used for reverse access. So I think it wont be a problem.

Comment: yes the problem is when it tries to find it as a link, it does not find the key in the dictionary

Comment: so that means I have to use attribute name and related_name same, in "companyDescription"  model

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little too late. You need to create a resources file in your app.

```html
class companyDescriptionResource(resources.ModelResource):
        class Meta:
        model = companyDescription
        import_id_fields = ['comDetail']
```